# Animate absolute div

Tags: html, css

Got an absolute div inside relative, and i need that absolute div to dive out on container hover.

Basic html would be

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="animated t50">See more</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animated {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5%;
}
.t50 {
    transition :0.5s;
    /*and further on with all the prefixes*/
}
.container:hover > .animated {
    bottom: 5%;
}
```

so, apparently there is something i don't know...

Comment: What is happening right now? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: .animated simply doesn't move

Comment: [Your code as of right now, pasted into JSFiddle, works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/yde2sauf/)

Comment: so weird... doesn't work on my site

Answer (score 0):

You must set `overflow: visible` on the parent container.

Here's an example on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/luhekatale/1/

Comment: yeah, but that way, "see more" will be visible, and i need it to dive out of "nowhere"

Comment: You mean _Show more_ should be initially hidden? If that's the case, just reverse the values of the `bottom` property, so initially it's set to let's say `-10%` and on hover it's `0%`. Or is it something else you're looking to achieve?